# Text from .txt file to textview where the .txt file is retrieved from parse.com

Tags: android, android-listview, parse-platform

My app contains a list view. When a list view item is clicked a new activity should open containing text. I want text to be retrieved from .txt files that I put in parse.com. But when I click the purview item a blank activity opens with no text. What shall I do?

Please help me
Here is my code

**main activity.java**

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import com.parse.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.util.*;
import android.util.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
private List<Textfile> textfilelist = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(this, "Hwq4ExtHsfHimcHFO3596nYv4dcwd6MX2hdIC7wN", "x7iF0nUMRS1T1boXBOAHhwNI8HUkhGuGapJFksI6");

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

    // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
}

private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("loading");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array
        textfilelist = new ArrayList<Textfile>();
        try {
            // Locate the class table named "TestText" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "TestText");

            query.orderByDescending("_created_at");
            ob= query.find();

            for (ParseObject txtobject : ob) {
                // Locate images in flag column
                ParseFile image = (ParseFile) txtobject.get("image");

                Textfile map = new Textfile();
                map.setText((String) txtobject.get("text"));
                map.setTxtview((String) txtobject.get("textfile"));
                map.setImage(image.getUrl());
                textfilelist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                                      textfilelist);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        }



}
```

**text file.java**

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

public class Textfile

{

private String text;
private String image;
private String txtview;

public void setTxtview(String txtview)
{
    this.txtview = txtview;
}

public String getTxtview()
{
    return txtview;
}

public void setImage(String image)
{
    this.image = image;
}

public String getImage()
{
    return image;
}



public void setText(String text)
{
    this.text = text;
}

public String getText()
{
    return text;
}}
```

**listview adapter.java**

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.content.*;
import java.util.*;
import android.view.View.*;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

// Declare Variables
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
private List<Textfile> textfilelist = null;
private ArrayList<Textfile> arraylist;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
                       List<Textfile> textfilelist) {
    this.context = context;
    this.textfilelist = textfilelist;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Textfile>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(textfilelist);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);

    }

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView heading;
    ImageView mainimage;
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    return textfilelist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    return textfilelist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
    holder.heading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_itemTextView);
    holder.mainimage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_itemImageView);
    view.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.heading.setText(textfilelist.get(position).getText());

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(textfilelist.get(position).getImage(),
                             holder.mainimage);


    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
                intent.putExtra("text",
                                (textfilelist.get(position).getTxtview());
                // Pass all data flag
                intent.putExtra("image",
                                (textfilelist.get(position).getImage()));
                // Start SingleItemView Class

                context.startActivity(intent);
                }
                });



    // TODO: Implement this method
    return view;
 }
```

}

**singleitemview.java**

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class SingleItemView extends Activity
{
String text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    text= i.getStringExtra("textfile");

    TextView txt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singleitemviewTextView);

    txt.setText(text);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's just a simple typo. You are putting String to the intent with name "text", and then you are trying to get this String using name "textfile".

Your onClick code:

```
intent.putExtra("text", (textfilelist.get(position).getText()));
```

Your activity code:

```
text= i.getStringExtra("textfile");
```

**Should be:**

```
text= i.getStringExtra("text");
```

**Edit:**
adapter:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
            intent.putExtra("text",
                            (textfilelist.get(position).getTxtview());
            // Pass all data flag
            intent.putExtra("image",
                            (textfilelist.get(position).getImage()));

            intent.putExtra("textfile",
                            (textfilelist.get(position).getTxtview()));
            // Start SingleItemView Class

            context.startActivity(intent);
            }
            });
```

activity:

```
            @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // TODO: Implement this method
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);

            Intent i = getIntent();

            text= i.getStringExtra("textfile");

            TextView txt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singleitemviewTextView);

            txt.setText(text);
        }
```

**If the rest is ok it should work**

Comment: But I have my .txt files under the column "text file" in my parse.com object and I want to retrieve text from the .txt files into my activity

Comment: Yeach, but you had put to the intent the result of "textfilelist.get(position).getText()", and then in singleitemview Activity you tried to get string from that intent with the name "textfile" (which haven't existed). Your intent **does not** have the item called "textfile". 


**Solution:** in adapter: `intent.putExtra("textfile",
                                (textfilelist.get(position).getTxtview()));`

Comment: Or if you have any other methods of retrieving text from .txt files into liistview help me

Comment: I think in singleitemview activity instead of text=I.getstring extra("text file") we should pass the text to be read from .txt files

Comment: Check the edit. If its not working, your TextFile objects dont have the field "txtview" set. Check also #getString instead of #get in your Parse code.

Comment: Please use breakpoints and debbuging to check if your TextFile objects are filled with data. I think they are not and the problem is in Parse code. Check also the content of your "ob" list. You should have done it before making this question.